# Use TinyMCE with Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, tinymce

I'm trying to use TinyMCE plugin with Vue.js, I'm doing the tutorial from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinymce/tinymce-vue). I'm doing by adding **.js** file because I'm not using a module loader.

Trying to display my app I get the following error message:

> Unknown custom element: **< editor >** - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option

On app.js I have the following code:

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
var Editor = require('@tinymce/tinymce-vue');

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   data :{
     menu : 0
   },
   components: {
     'editor': Editor // <- Important part
    },
    methods:{

    }
});
```

And on my vue component I have this tag:

```
<editor api-key="..." :init="{}"></editor>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Sorry, my fault, I add the code that I use for that var Editor = ...

Comment: @BoussadjraBrahim Instead of var Editor ....? Because if I use both npm run dev sent me an error.

Comment: You need to add `editor: Editor` to the components of your `ExampleComponent.vue` (and move the require line to its script) check App.vue here: https://codesandbox.io/s/oql0pwr4y

Comment: @ChrisG Thanks!! Could you post something as answer !